# Batch File for sort urls

Tags: sorting, batch-file, url

I need Batch file for create like this example :

▬ Google.com ▬

▬ Yahoo.com ▬

▬ Bing.com ▬

Also I have more links for this url in link.txt

```
http://drive.google.com
http://gallery.bing.com
http://mail.yahoo.com
http://video.google.com
http://brb.yahoo.com
http:/map.bing.com
```

I want After Run Batch file show links in below title like this :

```
▬ Google.com ▬
http://drive.google.com
http://video.google.com

▬ Yahoo.com ▬
http://mail.yahoo.com
http://brb.yahoo.com

▬ Bing.com ▬
http://gallery.bing.com
http:/map.bing.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a following sample script?

#### Flow :

1. Retrieve lines included google.com, yahoo.com and bing.com from "link.txt" and import them to array.

   - `if not "!val:google.com=!" == "!val!"` means when a line (`val`) includes `google.com`, set commands are run.
2. Display elements in each array.

#### Sample script :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set g=0
set y=0
set b=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in (link.txt) do (
    set val=%%a
    if not "!val:google.com=!" == "!val!" (
        set google[!g!]=!val!
        set /a g+=1
    )
    if not "!val:yahoo.com=!" == "!val!" (
        set yahoo[!y!]=!val!
        set /a y+=1
    )
    if not "!val:bing.com=!" == "!val!" (
        set bing[!b!]=!val!
        set /a b+=1
    )
)
set /a g-=1
set /a y-=1
set /a b-=1

echo - Google.com -
for /L %%i in (0,1,!g!) do echo !google[%%i]!
echo.
echo - Yahoo.com -
for /L %%i in (0,1,!y!) do echo !yahoo[%%i]!
echo.
echo - Bing.com -
for /L %%i in (0,1,!b!) do echo !bing[%%i]!
```

#### Result :

```
- Google.com -
http://drive.google.com
http://video.google.com

- Yahoo.com -
http://mail.yahoo.com
http://brb.yahoo.com

- Bing.com -
http://gallery.bing.com
http:/map.bing.com
```

#### Note :

1. This sample script can be used for the case that the URLs include `google.com`, `yahoo.com` and `bing.com`. So if there is an URL of `http://google.com.yahoo.com`, the result is displayed at both `google.com` and `yahoo.com`.
2. The order of each result which is displayed is followed for the order of link.txt.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

If you want to save the result as a text data using the batch file, please modify as follows. **When this modification is done, `link.txt` is overwritten by the result. So please be careful.** If you want to add the result to `link.txt`, please change from `echo - Google.com - > %outputfile%` to `echo - Google.com - >> %outputfile%`.

#### From :

```
echo - Google.com -
for /L %%i in (0,1,!g!) do echo !google[%%i]!
echo.
echo - Yahoo.com -
for /L %%i in (0,1,!y!) do echo !yahoo[%%i]!
echo.
echo - Bing.com -
for /L %%i in (0,1,!b!) do echo !bing[%%i]!
```

#### To :

```
set outputfile=link.txt
echo - Google.com - > %outputfile%
for /L %%i in (0,1,!g!) do echo !google[%%i]! >> %outputfile%
echo. >> %outputfile%
echo - Yahoo.com - >> %outputfile%
for /L %%i in (0,1,!y!) do echo !yahoo[%%i]! >> %outputfile%
echo. >> %outputfile%
echo - Bing.com - >> %outputfile%
for /L %%i in (0,1,!b!) do echo !bing[%%i]! >> %outputfile%
```

Comment: But result not save in link.txt. I run Batch-file but not see Result

Comment: @moh3en I'm sorry for the inconvenient. I updated my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @moh3en Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

This simpler Batch file don't requires to explicitly write the target sites; it works with any urls placed in the file *with the same format of the example data*.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Sort and store urls
for /F "tokens=1* delims=." %%a in (link.txt) do (
   set "name[%%b]=!name[%%b]! %%a.%%b"
)

rem Output sorted urls
(for /F "tokens=2* delims=[]=" %%a in ('set name[') do (
   echo - %%a -
   for %%c in (%%b) do echo %%c
   echo/
)) > link.txt
```

Result:

```
- bing.com -
http://gallery.bing.com
http:/map.bing.com

- google.com -
http://drive.google.com
http://video.google.com

- yahoo.com -
http://mail.yahoo.com
http://brb.yahoo.com
```